# Why is the assignment in a function ignored?

Tags: bash, function, scope, variable-assignment

Consider following code:

```
zzz=2

function f()
{
    zzz=4
}

$(f)
echo $zzz
```

Why is the assignment (`zzz=4`) ignored? I thought I knew what `$( )` does - it takes everything written to stdout and pastes it verbatim in the place where it's used. But why would that affect assignments to a global variable?

Comment: But `f` *doesn't* write anything to standard output; the command substitution serves no purpose here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `$(...)` runs in a subshell. Changes from a subshell are not visible in the parent shell.

From [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution):

> Bash performs the expansion by executing command in a subshell environment ...

and a subshell creates a separate process, which has a separate [command execution environment](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Execution-Environment).

It's the same as:

```
( 
   f
)
```

The `( .. )` also creates a subshell, but does not capture stdout.

Comment: Is there any way to pass some information from within `$( )` to the outside world (without using files) other than printing to stdout?

Comment: I think no, not really. You can print to a file descriptor previously opened, but that's really a file, even if opened to process substitution. Just go with a temporary file, that's how bash works.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you calling it in a subshell at all?

```
zzz=2
f() { zzz=4; }
$(f)            # assigns COPY of zzz, then goes POOF
echo $zzz
f               # assigns to zzz
echo $zzz
```

By running it in a subshell you are creating a child environment which gets the variable assigned, then evaporates.

Comment: Additionally, `$(f)` tries to run the output of `f` as a command, but there isn't any.

Answer (score 1):

Other answer is correctly pointed out that `$()` will create a subshell and you will have separate execution environment from parent shell.

```
zzz=2

function f()
{
   echo zzz=4
}

eval $(f)
echo $zzz
```

You can overcome this problem by using `eval` . First print the desired assignment statement inside the function and then evaluate that statement in the caller code.

Note: Please note that, `eval` is having some caveats and should be avoided ,unless you know for sure the behavior of your code.

Comment: Why are you adding even *more* overhead to a situation where the command substitution was never necessary in the first place?

Comment: this is added as a general answer when command substitution is required. as OP used it here.

Comment: I don't think the OP knows why they are using command substitution. Nothing suggests it is required.

Comment: agreed sir,as I said, this is not to relevant to this case but in general case "when" command substitution is required. I have already added a note stating not a preferred solution.

Comment: There's no need to introduce a "general case" here.

Comment: respectfully disagree sir, you have already shown your disagreement with the downvote which I respect. its a general case only, there is no harm in listing things when it comes with warning.

Comment: Honestly, sometimes it's harder to get help from SO than to solve the problem oneself. To ask a question here one has to provide a minimum viable example as too much unnecessary code makes it harder for others to understand the gist of the problem... but because many people here **always assume the OP doesn't know what they're doing** sometimes it's better to put some unnecessary code or one will get accused of asking about something else than they are. @PS. Thanks for not being one of said people. chepner, command substitution is the gist of my question but the example didn't need to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the subshell around f.

Assuming you really had no use for a subshell, the code should look something like:

```
zzz=2

function f()
{
    zzz=4
}

f
echo $zzz
```

You're telling it that function f needs to be executed in a different shell, so it won't change the varaible.

Comment: The `$( )` is the gist of my question - without it the assignment is trivial and works without a problem. However, the example I provided didn't need to actually use `$( )`'s result for it to showcase the specific problem.